# Change background colour of an auto clicked hyperlink in excel

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have a snippet of vba that should change the background colour of an auto generated hyperlink when the link is clicked (and doesn't produce an error

This is what should happen

```
Is this a link?
No? Ignore. Yes? Carry on

Does this link go anywhere?
No? Change background colour. Yes? Carry on

Repeat for every selected link
```

My code is as such:

```
    Sub Click_Links()

    Dim links As Hyperlink
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("Range1")

' i = 0
On Error Resume Next
' n = 1 / i
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
'If there are no errors'

links.Parent.Interior.Color = 100
'Change bg colour'
   '  On Error Resume Next

Else
    On Error GoTo 0
    For Each links In rng.Hyperlinks
    'Every Line'
    links.Follow
    'Click the link'
     Next links
     'Go to next link to check'


End If
End Sub
```

When I run the script, nothing happens except the screen flickers. While messing with the code, I had issues with the `End If` but it basically magically dissapeared? before THAT, the script ran, changed one background colour and then stopped working straight after

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: You DIM i and n, but don't use their values. You loop through a selection, but it is better to explicitly define the range you want to loop through, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: Also you don't see any errors in your code, because you explicitly turned them off. Remove your `On Error Resume Next` to see the errors

Comment: Thanks! I've managed to get them working by opening all the links, but the background colour doesn't change. Looks like it's to do with `If Err.Number <> 0 Then` I've updated my code to reflect

Comment: You need to change the color inside the for loop

Comment: @pnuts, and its gone....